# Regressing a 7-level ordinal variable using linear regression in a sample of 1000

Tags: regression, ordinal-data

I have a dependent variable which has responses on scale of 1-7 and i am regressing it against the variable which are continuous and categorical in nature. is using linear regression even appropriate?

What would be the best approach to deal with such a case?

Comment: I am considerting to dummy code the variable into low and high based on response scale and then run logistic model, as our area of interest is whats driving the change from low to high.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered logit is one such approach, but makes some parametric assumptions.

Broadly, it treats each tier of dependent variables as distributed p/(1-p), and can move up to the next tier with a high enough response.  This particular shape results in lots of conversation about odds-ratios.

Specifically, it also assumes that the odds ratios are proportional, the logs occur in a arithmetic sequence: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit

Comment: This is helpful but stops just as it is getting started. Could you expand on "parametric assumptions"?